# Disable Crash Wine Debian Linux

Tags: linux, debian, wine, trinitycore

so i'm currently running my world of warcraft server on Linux Debian 9 
And I've managed to setup everything properly but whenever i restart my 'worldserver.exe' it just doesn't restart. 
This is the codes i use to run worldserver.exe and restart it.

At start i make restarter file with the following information :

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
wine worldserver.exe 
sleep 1
done
```

Then i change the 'chmod' to 777 using this :

```
sudo chmod 777 restarter.sh
```

At the end i run the autorestarter as following :

```
screen -AmdS world ./restarter.sh
```

Everything in this part works perfectly unless i type in .server restart 10 + 
This command will just close worldserver.exe 
and than it comes the crash no logs really because it's normal common on windows too I've used a method in windows which is something similar to this : 
[LINK](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-program-has-stopped-working-error-dialog-in-windows-server-2008/)
But since i'm using Wine in Linux i was wondering how would it goes for it ?

Comment: Anyone can help here ? or i'm in the wrong place...

Comment: Why use wine for run server on debian!!! you can compile your source on debian! not need to use wine!